# Chef Recipe (RUBY)

Tags: ruby, devops, chef-infra

I'm working on a chef recipe that will pull down a program installer depending on the memory total in a linux server. If the memory total is 8GB or more install .... if the memory is less than 8GB then install ... . Does anybody happen to know how to script this?
Chef is ruby based.
Within my chef recipes I have attempted the following, but had no success.

```
puts "***** Linux server node['platform_family']=#{node['platform_family']}"
puts "***** Linux server node['memory.total']=#{node['memory.total']}"
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
puts "*****#{node['platform_family']}"
puts "*****#{node['memory.total']}"

if node['platform_family'] == 'debian' && node['memory.total'] >= 7000000
   remote_file '/tmp'
        source 'local file'
        action :create
   end
elsif
  remote_file '/tmp'
       source 'external file'
       action :create
  end
```

Comment: The elsif should be a else as you have no condition after it. Out of that and the missing end, your code seems correct for what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

The `remote_file` resource can written in a better way (once) if we can compute the value of `source` property beforehand. Also since you have shown comparison of `node['platform_family']`, it appears you would need to match for OS families other than `debian` as well.

Below code will match for `platform_family` and `['memory']['total']` and set a value that we can use with the `source` property.

```rb
mem = node['memory']['total'][/\d*/].to_i

remote_src = case node['platform_family']
when 'debian'
  mem >= 7000000 ? 'local file' : 'remote file'
when 'redhat'
  mem >= 7000000 ? 'some file' : 'some other file'
# when some other OS family if required
end

remote_file '/tmp/somefile' do
  source remote_src
  action :create
end
```

Note that I'm using [ternary operator](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/10/ruby-ternary-operator/) as an alternative to `if` / `else` within `when` condition of `case` statement.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I was wondering if you could explain what '[/\d*/] does.

Comment: That's a Ruby [regular expression](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/) that returns all continuous numeric/digit (/`\d*/)` characters in the given input.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only ever going to use this recipe in Linux, then this method will work:

```
memory_in_megabytes = node.memory.total[/\d*/].to_i / 1024

if memory_in_megabytes > 512
  ## Do your thing!
end
```

Different OSes report this value differently and not always in the same format though. So if you want to support any system platform (just in case this has a use for someone not using Linux) this would be a far better option:

```
memory_in_megabytes = case node['os']
when /.*bsd/
  node.memory.total.to_i / 1024 / 1024
when 'linux'
  node.memory.total[/\d*/].to_i / 1024
when 'darwin'
  node.memory.total[/\d*/].to_i
when 'windows', 'solaris', 'hpux', 'aix'
  node.memory.total[/\d*/].to_i / 1024
end

if memory_in_megabytes > 512
  ## Do your thing!
end
```

Comment: When I run that I receive the following error   NoMethodError
       -------------
       undefined method `memory' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute

Comment: The method syntax to access node attributes was [deprecated for a long time and was finally removed in Chef 13](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_attributes/). You can now access the attribute as `node['memory']['total']`.